# Translate Stata code into R code: glm

Tags: r, syntax, stata

I have a glm-formula in Stata, which I need to "translate" into R. I have a rough idea how it could look like, but I'm not sure, as I never used Stata.

It's a glm with ineraction term, where the interaction term `ridit_survey` is the product of the two terms `ridit*survey` (i.e., in Stata: `ridit_survey=ridit*survey`.

Here is model 1 in Stata

```
xi: glm smoking ridit survey ridit_survey age if men==1, fam(bin) link(log) nolog eform
```

And I would translate it into R like this:

```
fit <- glm(xi ~ smoking + age + ridit * survey, family = binomial("log"),
           data = subset(dataframe, subset = men == 1))
```

And the second model:

```
xi:glm smoking ridit survey ridit_survey age if men==1, fam(bin) link(identity)
```

which I would translate into

```
fit <- glm(xi ~ smoking + age + ridit * survey, family = binomial("identity"),
           data = subset(dataframe, subset = men == 1))
```

Is this correct (and if not, how would it be correct)?

Comment: I don't have STATA at hand, so I can't install and check, unfortunately.

Comment: The `xi:` in your Stata [NB spelling] call is redundant as you specify  interactions through your additional variable. R people can note that there is nothing to translate there. `nolog` just tunes how much output you get. `eform` specifies exponentiated coefficients. Help is publicly available at http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?glm

Comment: Ok, so `smoking` is the outcome? Thanks, I think that answers my question! If you like, you could convert your comment into an answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: Absolutely: `xi:` is a command prefix and **not** a variable name. I can't be confident of what R code to use, as I am not a frequent user at all.